# C++ error when using stream buffers directly with ?: operator

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

When I try to use a ternary conditional operator (?:) with stream buffer redirection, gcc produces 'synthesized method first required here' error. What is the problem, and how to correct the following program?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << cin.rdbuf();    //OK
    ofstream("tmp.txt") << cin.rdbuf(); //OK

    int i=1;
    (i > 1 ? ofstream("tmp.txt") : cout) << cin.rdbuf(); //Compilation ERROR. Why?
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with gcc4.4:

```
...    
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/ios_base.h: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_ios<char,   std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’:  
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/ios_base.h:790: error: ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private  
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:47: error: within this context  
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_ostream<char,   std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<char,   std::char_traits<char> >&)’:  
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:56: note: **synthesized method** ‘std::basic_ios<char,   std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’   **first required here**   
../item1_1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:  
../item1_1.cpp:12: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ostream<char,   std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<char,   std::char_traits<char> >&)’ first required here
```

Comment: Removed STL tag. STL != standard library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This compiled OK with my version of clang, I *think* that it may be a gcc bug.

From my reading of the standard, `cout` is an *lvalue* of type `std::ostream` and `ofstream("tmp.txt")` is an *rvalue* of type `std::ofstream`.

Neither has any *cv-qualifiers* and `std::ostream` is a base class of `std::ofstream` so the conditional operator is valid an the result is an *rvalue* and has type `std::ostream`.

There is no copying of either operand implied.

> if `E1` and `E2` have class type, and the underlying class types are the same or one is a base class of the other: `E1` can be converted to match `E2` if the class of `T2` is the same type as, or a base class of, the class of `T1`, and the cv-qualification of `T2` is the same cv-qualification as, or a greater cv-qualification than, the cv-qualification of `T1`. If the conversion is applied, `E1` is changed to an rvalue of type `T2` that still refers to the original source class object (or the appropriate subobject thereof). [*Note:* that is, no copy is made. ]

The `operator<<` overload that you are using is a member of `std::ostream` so there is no need to bind a temporary to a non-const reference, the member can be called on a non-const *rvalue*.

```
basic_ostream<charT,traits>&
    basic_ostream<charT,traits>::operator<< (basic_streambuf<charT,traits>* sb);
```

**Edit**

Note that this has changed in C++0x. Now, if the result of a conditional expression is an *rvalue* a temporary copy is always made. As objects of type `ostream` are not copyable your code will not be valid in C++0x.

See here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#446

Comment: I have a recent clang and the OP's code doesn't compile for me in C++03 or C++0x modes.  Apple clang version 2.0 (trunk 125236) (based on LLVM 2.9svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin10
Thread model: posix

Comment: @HowardHinnant: My clang is a bit older but doesn't complain, strange.

Comment: You have answered my question. Indeed, C++0x changed the scheme for evaluating ? operator. New scheme could be found in this section of the standard:
5.16 Conditional operator [expr.cond]

Comment: Yes, I even thought that no C++03 compiler implements it that way. It would mean that the language would have rvalues whose dynamic type differs from the static type.

Comment: Could they make the error message any more obscure?  ha ha  I was getting the same message with my C++98 compiler (GCC 4.1.2 on RHEL 5.8), so this was helpful--thanks.  Followup question:  Does this mean you cannot have a copy-constructable class with a non-static stream object member?  It would need to be: (1) a static member so there is a single copy, or (2) a shared pointer (unmanaged, shallow copy in C++98), or (3) a reference (e.g., to a stream object in main)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional operator this way instead:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    ofstream file("tmp.txt");
    int i=1;
    (i > 1 ? file : cout) << cin.rdbuf();
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles for me on gcc 4.4.3.

Not quite the one-liner you were looking for, I know.

**NOTE**: As Evan pointed out in his comment, this will result in the file being created even if not needed.

Comment: That will create the file even when not needed. So it doesn't act exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possibilities here:

1. cout is of ostream type, the other (temporary) is ofstream, and they are not convertible to each other in any way
2. even if they are convertible the result is a temporary rvalue and it will not bind to operator<< as it requires nonconst lvalue reference.

Comment: The `ostream<<` overload that takes a `streambuf*` is a member function and you can call member functions on _rvalues_ of class type. No reference binding is needed.